# Getting text box control programatically throws System.NullReferenceException

Tags: vb.net, nullreferenceexception

I have a VB.Net Sub that loads values from a list into textboxes on a form (this form is where the sub is located). If I reference a text box *directly*, say `txt01.Text = "Blah"`, it works just fine; but if I reference the *same* text box programmatically, like `Me.Controls("txt01").Text = "Blah"`, I keep getting `System.NullReferenceException`.

Here's the code:

```
Private Sub lboxCodebooks_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As 
EventArgs) Handles lboxCodebooks.SelectedIndexChanged

    'On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    If lboxCodebooks.SelectedIndex < 0 Then GoTo CleanUpAndExit

    grpCodebook.Enabled = True

    Dim c As Codebook = CB.Item(lboxCodebooks.SelectedIndex)
    Dim ctlName As String
    Dim ctl As Control

    txtCodebookName.Text = c.Name

    For i As Integer = 1 To 93

        ctlName = "txt" & Format(i, "00")

        ctl = Me.Controls(ctlName) ' This sets ctl to Nothing - but why?

        ctl.Text = Mid(c.AlphaCodex, i, 1) ' NullReference error here.

    Next

CleanUpAndExit:
    On Error Resume Next

    c = Nothing

    Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    Call ErrorHandler(Err)
    Resume CleanUpAndExit

End Sub
```

What on earth am I doing wrong here?

Comment: If the control is in another container like a panel or groupbox it will be in *that* controls collection.  You arent checking if the return (`ctl`) is Nothing so you get the error.  You should also set `Option Strict On`

Comment: Wow... it's little things like that, that make me crazy.  >_<  Thanks!

Comment: also `On Error ....` has no place in NET code